# Simple apache rewrite rule disables .htaccess password authentification

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

I have that rule in my root / path

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?args=$1 [QSA,L]
```

and in /admin I have that rule

```
RewriteEngine On
AuthType Basic
AuthName "protected area"
AuthUserFile /home/www/admin/.htpasswd
require valid-user
```

The password protection works only when I comment the rewrite rule

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?args=$1 [QSA,L]
```

(When I enter the /admin/ url, I am redirected to /)

I use cpanel and centos7

This is very strange since I use that patterns with no issues on Debian.

I tried

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin [NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?args=$1 [QSA,L]
```

But I am still redirected to / when entering any /admin/ page.

Comment: "I am redirected to /" - What do you mean exactly? There is no "redirect" in the code you posted... it is an internal rewrite to `/index.php` in the root. What version of Apache are you on? (Or are you on LiteSpeed by chance?) Are you behind a front-end proxy of some kind? Do you have any other directives in these `.htaccess` files? When requesting `/admin/` (a physical directory) then the _condition_ that checks the filesystem would already exclude such a request (but it doesn't necessarily look like that is the rule being processed here).

Comment: As I understand it your actual issue is that requests to `/admin/` get internally rewritten to `/index.php` and _NOT_ that basic authentication is somehow magically disabled, right?

Comment: Are you sure you are not simply looking at a client side cached result from earlier implementation results? How did you check that?